# Creation of a dynamic service in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need a way to create a dynamic/generic rest client. My spring boot application need to connect to many third party clients, all of which have different request body, response body, some require special headers, while some require special authorization/authentication (e.g Basic Auth, JWT, HMAC etc).

So far I've managed to come up with the following client

```
public class GenericRestClient<T, V> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public V execute(RequestDetails requestDetails, T data, ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler,
            Class<V> genericClass) throws ResourceAccessException, Exception {

        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        HttpEntity<T> entity = new HttpEntity<T>(data, headers);
        ResponseEntity<V> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestDetails.getUrl(), requestDetails.getRequestType(),
                entity, genericClass);
        return response.getBody();
    }

}
```

But my question is. Is there a way now to generate all the necessary headers, authentication and authorization when all of them have different requirements? How can I do that?

Is there a way to store java code like a script (e.g., JTX) in the database and use them, or is there any better way to create my need?

I want it such that even if a new client comes, no further coding needs to  be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store configuration of every client in database. If you use JPA you will end up with class like that:

```
@Entity
class RestClientConfiguration{
    private String url;
    private Map<String,String> headers;

    //whatever data you need
}
```

Then you only need to pass `RestClientConfiguration` to your `GenericRestClient` class.

```
public class GenericRestClient<T, V> {

    public V execute(RequestDetails requestDetails, T data, ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler,
            Class<V> genericClass, RestClientConfiguration clientConfiguration) throws ResourceAccessException, Exception {

        String url = clientConfiguration.getUrl();
        Map<String, String> headerMap = clientConfiguration.getHeaders();

        //here add code which map headerMap which is a Map to HttpHeaders object


        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();


        HttpEntity<T> entity = new HttpEntity<T>(data, headers);
        ResponseEntity<V> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestDetails.getUrl(), requestDetails.getRequestType(),
                entity, genericClass);
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

That's it. Hope I got your needs well. Let me know if something is not clear and we will work it out :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it such that, even if a new client comes, no code is needed to be done. If the config could be taken from the database or a script for that matter? I want it to be extremely dynamic and generic.

Comment: I believe so. You can keep the configuration wherever you want and just set up `RestTemplate` Check out that tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder

Comment: But according to this I have to create a new rest template if a new configuration for a client shows up.

Comment: Exactly, and do you have something against that?

Comment: Well my team lead wants it to be such that, when a new client shows up, the changes must only be made in the database, and not in the code itself.

Comment: You don't need to made a change in the code at all! Take dynamic configuration from database and set up `RestTemplate`. It doesn't have to be set up when application starts. New `RestTemplate` can be created whenever you need. In your case when new client shows up.

Comment: Could you explain it in the answer then i'll vote it up. In what way could I do that, I am new to this, like what are the configurations that i need in my database, and how to hook it up to a restTemplate. It would be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: @MohendraAmatya I edited my answer. Check it out and let me know if this is clear

Comment: One last question sir; client A has HMAC authentication based on a unique id generated at runtime! And client B has Basic auth while client C requires just parameters in the url; how do we make them dynamic or how do we store them in the db?

Comment: Then your real life configuration will be a little bit more complex than what I proposed. You will probably need more than one table in db for that. For example you can have an enum with Auth type: NONE, BASIC, HMAC and so on. Depends on that value you will set up Rest Template object - it supports all types of auth